# Add external javascript library to odoo 12

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-12, erp

Hello i'm new to odoo and i'm using version 12, i want to add an external javascript library which is loading.io https://loading.io/progress/.

I don't know how to add it because i saw that it is not possible to use a cdn.

Any help or hint will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: `Installation: download loading bar JS and CSS files ( or, the zipped pack ) and include them in your HTML` - https://loading.io/progress/#installation - i.e. host them on your server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The add a Javascript or CSS asset to Odoo, extend the appropriate assets template.

This might be:

- `web.assets_frontend` for frontend web pages.
- `web.assets_backend` for backend webclient pages.
- `web.assets_common` for both backend and frontend.

The asset files, if bundled should be inside your module, in a `static/lib/css` and `static/lib/js` subdirectories.

For example:

```
<odoo>
  <template id="mymodule_web_assets" name="My Web Assets"
            inherit_id="web.assets_frontend">
     <xpath expr="." position="inside">

       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
             href="/<mymodule>/static/lib/css/loading-bar.css"/>
       <script type="text/javascript"
               src="/<mymodule>/static/lib/js/loading-bar.js"></script>

    </xpath>
  </template>
</odoo>
```